# C# ASP.NET Core : I am able to update data for only one table but the others are not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Am I doing something wrong?

I am not able to update data in my `LsstoreDetails` table but the `Lsstores` table is the only table that is updating the data in the database.

Whenever I debug, I can see that `model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn` is not null and has registered my input but it doesn't save it.

I am not sure what to do as I tried so many different methods and the same issue kept persisting.

I am not getting any errors.

It would be much appreciated if I could receive some help/guidance to resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Model class:

```
public class Manage
{
    public Lsstore Store { get; set; }

    public List<Lscity> Cities { get; set; }
    public List<Lscountry> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<LsstoreStatus> Status { get; set; }
    public List<LsstoreType> Types { get; set; }
    public List<Lsprovince> Provinces { get; set; }
    public List<LsstoreMall> Malls { get; set; }
    public List<Lsregion> Regions { get; set; }
    public List<LssubBrand> SubBrands { get; set; }
    public List <LsstoreBusinessHour> StoreBusinessHours { get; set; }
    public List<Lslanguage> Languages { get; set; }
    public List<Lsbanner> Banners { get; set; }

    public VwLsstoreMgmtInfo LsstoreMgmt { get; set; }
    public VwStoreKiboInfo StoreKiboInfo { get; set; }
    public LsstoreDetail StoreDetail { get; set; }      
}
```

A part of the view (it is in a form):

```
        <div class="mb-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Store.StoreDescription, "Store Name", 
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Store.StoreDescription, new { htmlAttributes 
            = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Store.StoreDescription, "", new { 
            @class = "text-danger" })
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group input-group-lg mb-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn, "Store Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#english" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">EN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#french" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">FR</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="english">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, rows = 10, cols = 60 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="french">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsFr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, rows = 10, cols = 60 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsFr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>             
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id, Manage model)
    {      
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
         
        // This part doesn't work
        var storeDetail = db.LsstoreDetails.Where(x => x.StoreId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (storeDetail != null)
        {
            storeDetail.StoreDetailsEn = model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        //-------------------------
        // This part works
        var data = db.Lsstores.Find(id);

        if (data != null)
        {
            data.StoreDescription = model.Store.StoreDescription;
            data.Address = model.Store.Address;
            data.Local = model.Store.Local;
            data.Zip = model.Store.Zip;
            data.Sqft = model.Store.Sqft;
            data.Fax2 = model.Store.Fax2;
            data.Phone1 = model.Store.Phone1;
            data.Fax1 = model.Store.Fax1;
            data.RegisterCount = model.Store.RegisterCount;
            data.PosVersion = model.Store.PosVersion;
            data.Latitude = model.Store.Latitude;
            data.Longitude = model.Store.Longitude;
            data.OpenDate = model.Store.OpenDate;
            data.CloseDate = model.Store.CloseDate;
            data.ModifiedDate = model.Store.ModifiedDate;
            data.ModifiedBy = model.Store.ModifiedBy;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        //------------------------------------------

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
        }
   }
```

Comment: Does this line give you anything? `db.LsstoreDetails.Where(x => x.StoreId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: It extracts the data from the database which gives me the LsstoreDetails with the right StoreId

Comment: How are you checking the DB to verify the changes?

Comment: Do your classes have correct Navigation Properites?

Comment: *Don't* call `SaveChanges` multiple times. `SaveChanges` will persist all pending changes in a single internal transaction. It's meant to be called only at the very last moment, when you're sure you want to commit all changes. `SaveChanges` will resolve any auto-generated ID values as well

Comment: If you want to modify a store and its details *load the store only* and modify all the loaded objects, including the details. Then call `SaveChanges`. That means you only need a `var store = db.Lsstores.Find(id);` at the top, and a `store.Details[0].StoreDetailsEn = model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn;` along with the other changes. A single `SaveChanges` at the end will persist all changes

Comment: An _optional_ int Id and the action returns notfound when it's null? And that's the only time it returns notfound? Wut?

Comment: BTW `NotFound` should be returned if no `store` is found, not if the request is invalid. A `null` ID is an invalid request

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you wanted to accomplish, but got confused along the way, i would suggest you read about [auto mapper](https://automapper.org/) it would help clean up your code.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, Manage model)
{      
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
     
    // This part doesn't work
    var storeDetail = db.LsstoreDetails.Where(x => x.StoreId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (storeDetail != null)
    {
        storeDetail.StoreDetailsEn = model.StoreDetail.StoreDetailsEn;
        db.LsstoreDetails.update(storeDetail);
    }

    //-------------------------
    // This part works
    var data = db.Lsstores.Find(id);

    if (data != null)
    {
        data.StoreDescription = model.Store.StoreDescription;
        data.Address = model.Store.Address;
        data.Local = model.Store.Local;
        data.Zip = model.Store.Zip;
        data.Sqft = model.Store.Sqft;
        data.Fax2 = model.Store.Fax2;
        data.Phone1 = model.Store.Phone1;
        data.Fax1 = model.Store.Fax1;
        data.RegisterCount = model.Store.RegisterCount;
        data.PosVersion = model.Store.PosVersion;
        data.Latitude = model.Store.Latitude;
        data.Longitude = model.Store.Longitude;
        data.OpenDate = model.Store.OpenDate;
        data.CloseDate = model.Store.CloseDate;
        data.ModifiedDate = model.Store.ModifiedDate;
        data.ModifiedBy = model.Store.ModifiedBy;
        db.Lsstores.update(data);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();

    //------------------------------------------

    return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }}
```

Comment: There's no reason to call `Update`. EF already tracks changes, so already knows the loaded object was modified

Comment: it depends on the version of EF you are using and then it wouldn't kill